How to Retrieve All Fields from an Object in Salesforce API Search Query?
I'm using the following query to retrieve articles from the Knowledge__kav object:
{{_endpoint}}/services/data/v{{version}}/search/?q=FIND+{"renew" OR "ordering"}+IN+ALL+FIELDS+RETURNING+Knowledge__kav

However, this query only returns the IDs of the articles and does not include other fields like Title. When I specify the title separately, it works as expected:
{{_endpoint}}/services/data/v{{version}}/search/?q=FIND+{"renew" OR "ordering"}+IN+ALL+FIELDS+RETURNING+Knowledge__kav(Id,+Title)

My question is: What should I do to retrieve all fields of the Knowledge__kav object in a single query?

Yes, this is possible. You will need to use FIELDS(ALL) in your query.
For example:
FIND {searchTerm} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Knowledge__kav(FIELDS(ALL) LIMIT 200)

You will have to include a LIMIT and the most you can retrieve in one query is 200.
To get around this limit you can specify FIELDS(STANDARD) instead but it will not return any custom fields.

Thank you this is exactly what I needed!
